# Update Activity History without refreshing page in Open CTI

Tags: apex, visualforce, opencti

I am working on a project using Open CTI.

I am saving the call log in Task object using saveLog() method. And to update the Activity History I am using refreshPage() method. This work as long as I am on the detail page for the contact.

Is there any other way to update Activity history if I am not in the detail page.

Here is my code:

```
sforce.interaction.saveLog('Task', saveParams);//save it to Task object
sforce.interaction.refreshPage();//refresh current active tab to update Activity History
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [refreshRelatedList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_refreshrelatedlist.htm) to update the Activity History.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console integration toolkit in order to refresh the tabs you want. It depends on where you will be calling saveLog from how you implement it. Here is one example:

If contact is primary tab and you're in a case subtab of that contact when you create the task, or even with an Account primary tab where contact is a subtab and you're on the Account's detail view, you can run code like this to refresh all the subtabs under the primary tab which is focused.

```
sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(refreshTab);
var refreshTab = function refreshTab(result) {
    sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(result.id, true);
};
```

There are a lot of other methods available that can help such as refreshing a specified subtab or getting a list of all open tabs. Because the best solution depends heavily on your agents' use case you can check the docs to get more ideas.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/